# How to find the last one digit of $8^{97}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> What will be the units digit of:
>   $8^{97}$

I know I will have to start like:

$8^1$, then $8^2, 8^3$ etc...

is there a shorter method to finding the units/digit?

Comment: if you know modular arithmetic then work $\pmod{10}$.

Comment: If you don't know modular arithmetic then calculate a few out, you will begin to see a pattern, hopefully.

Comment: $8,4,2,6,8,4,2,6,8,\dots$

Comment: jesus christ there are way too many conceptual duplicates on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order followed by laSt digits of powers of 8 is $8,4,2,6,8,4..$ so last digit of $8^4=6$ so last digit of $8^{96}$ is also $6$ hence last one digit of $8^{97}=6.8=8$. Thus last digit of $8^{97}=8$.

Comment: Note you can also do it by modular division.

Answer (score 4):

Hint for proof:

Notice that when you take a product of two numbers the final digit of the result only depends on the final digit of each original factor. Why should that be the case?

Why does this imply that taking powers of 8 will give a pattern in the final digit? In fact this is true for any natural number, not just 8, and this pattern will always be of a specific sort.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, which, amazingly, only appears in this answer.

Comment: True! +1 for the first paragraph!

Answer (score 1):

If you know modular arithmetic: find $8^{97} \mod 10$

Else, observe:

$8^1=8$

$8^2=64$

$8^3=512$

$8^4=4096$

$8^5=32768$

if you further observe,

1. $n=1,5,9,...$ has last digit 8,
2. $n=2,6,10,...$ has last digit 4,
3. $n=3,7,11,...$ has last digit 2,

and 4. $n=4,8,12,...$ has last digit 6,

Which sequence does 97 belong?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Compute $8^1,8^2,8^3,8^4,8^5,...$ and watch the last digit!

Answer (score 0):

$8^1$ end in 8, $8^2$ ends in 6, $8^3$ ends in 4, $8^4$ ends in 6, $8^5$ ends in 8 so the pattern repeats itself. Since $97$ is one more than a multiple of 4, it has the same units digit as $8^1$, $8^5$, $8^9$, etc. So the last digit of $8^{97}$ is 8.

If you do know modular arithmetic: 
$8^{97} \equiv 8^7 \equiv (4^3)^2 \cdot 8 \equiv 4^2\cdot 8 \equiv 6 \cdot 8 \equiv 8 \mod 10$ so 8 is the units digit.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the geometric progression formula which is in the form a*r^(n-1)

"a" represents the first digit in the sequence.

"r" represents the ratio between every 2 successive numbers in the sequence

"n" represents the position of the number you are looking for.

So......

a=8^1=1

r=8^2/8^1=8^3/8^2=(well, you get the idea)

r=8

n=97

8*8^(97-1)

Unfortunately I use a 6 bit calculator which will give me the wrong value so just calculate for yourself 8^96 then multiply by8.